# How to call function from another file

Tags: flutter

I have two different .dart file.

sidebar file, there is a function in this class to something

```
    class SideBar extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _SideBarState createState() => _SideBarState();
    }

    class _SideBarState extends State<SideBar>
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin<SideBar> { 

     void onIconPressed() {
          print('123');
      }

    }
```

homescreen file;

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static String routeName = "/HomeScreen";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
                   onPressed: (){ }, ///////////////////////where i try to implement function
```

I want the call this function in another file. What i tried import sidebar.dart file as sidebar. Then call function like sidebar.onIconPressed() But nothing work. I looked widget communication thing but couldnt get it. Is there any easy way to solve this problem.

**Edit:** The reason why my solution not work because I acces the void which has a setstate. Thats why I always get null message

Comment: In your home screen where do you use ``SideBar`` Widget?

Comment: I solve the question. What I was trying to do change statefull content(via function from another file). But it didnt work. I implement the code to main file.

Comment: also I add one answer, you can see it

Answer (score 1):

```
class SideBar extends StatefulWidget {

      @override
      _SideBarState createState() => _SideBarState();
    }

    class _SideBarState extends State<SideBar>
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin<SideBar> { 


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
             onPressed: (){ 
                onIconPressed();
       }, 
       
     void onIconPressed() {
          print('123');
      }

    }



class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static String routeName = "/HomeScreen";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return SideBar(....
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object for your class then you would be able to call the function through the object.

//define the object inside HomeScreen class
final SideBar sidebar = SideBar();

then in onPressed call the function sidebar. onIconPressed();

```
class SideBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SideBarState createState() => _SideBarState();

  void onIconPressed() {
    print('123');
  }
}

class _SideBarState extends State<SideBar>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin<SideBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(); 
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static String routeName = "/HomeScreen";
  SideBar s = new SideBar();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async => false,
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(leading: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
              onPressed: () {
                s.onIconPressed();
              });
        }))));
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually I tried this method too. but it gave me this error: The method 'onIconPressed' isn't defined for the type 'SideBar'.